# Mongo doesn't maintain $sort order after $skip when sort values are same

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

My data looks like this:

```
{ _id: 1, x: "abc", y: "def"}
{ _id: 2, x: "abc", y: "efg"}
{ _id: 3, x: "xxx", y: "xxx"}
```

My query looks like this:

```
db.col.aggregate([{ $sort: { x: 1 } },{ $skip: 0 } ])
```

When I run that query, i see everything in order: 1, 2, 3
When I change `skip` to 1, i get 1,3
When it does the sort, is it internally recognizing that docs 1 and 2 are sorted on the same value and using a different method to choose which to use if skipping? Is there any way around this?

Comment: Use `$sort` with the`_id` field or some timestamp field as well. Else both the values(abc) are same for it. `{ $sort: { x: 1, _id: 1 } }`

Comment: this works but i was hoping to avoid or have a better understanding of why, but i think that's what i'm going to have to do

Answer (score 2):

Your query is right may be version issue create problem

```
db.col.aggregate([{ $sort: { x: 1, _id: 1 } }, { $skip: 1 } ])
```

you can use [sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) and [skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/)

```
db.col.find({ }).sort( { x: 1, _id: 1 } ).skip(1);
```

Skip is used number of first `n` doc skip. Mongodb not have offset like `mysql`

Answer (score 1):

Because you have same values for the `x` field, you need to use one more field in the `$sort` stage and probably the `_id` is the best to use.

```
{ $sort: { x: 1, _id: 1 } }
```